# React Passing Same Prop Twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a SideBar navigation component, that holds an open/close state.
This state is drilled down to childs (SideBarButton) to perform conditional CSS styling.

Strange thing is, that the SideBarButton, despite receiving the prop once, it is shown twice in the rendered tree, and always taking the `false` value.

Any one any idea why?

NavigationLinksView receives isOpenSideNav:

```
  <div className={styles.root}>
      <NavigationLinksView
        isOpenSideNav={isOpenSideNav}
        navigationLinksList={navigationLinksTop}
      />
      <NavigationLinksView
        isOpenSideNav={isOpenSideNav}
        navigationLinksList={navigationLinksBottom}
      />
    </div>
```

NavigationLinksView.js:

```
const NavigationLinksView = ({isOpenSideNav, navigationLinksList}) => {
  return (
    <ul
      className={styles.root}
    >
      {_.map(navigationLinksList, (navigationItem, idx) => {
        const {sideMenuContent, name} = navigationItem;
        if (sideMenuContent) {
          return (
            <SideBarButtonWithSubMenu
              key={`${name}_${idx}`}
              isOpensideNav={isOpenSideNav}
              navigationItem={navigationItem}
            />
          );
        }
        return (
          <SideBarButton
            key={`${name}_${idx}`}
            isOpensideNav={isOpenSideNav}
            navigationItem={navigationItem}
          />
        );
      })}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Yet, each SidebarButton or SideBarButtonWithSubMenu has problems reading that prop:

```
const SideBarButton = ({navigationItem, isOpenSideNav}) => {
  const {id, className, withSeparator, disabled, to, name, analytics, icon} = navigationItem;
  console.log({isOpenSideNav, comp: 'SideBarButton'});

  const {icon: iconName, color, hoverColor} = icon;
  const currentPathLink = to || `/${id}`;
  const location = useLocation();
  const activePath = _.split(location.pathname, '/')[1] === id;
  const {translate} = useLocalisationService();

  return (
    <li key={name} className={classNames(styles.root, {[styles.disabled]: disabled})}>
      {withSeparator && <div className={styles.separator}/>}
      <Link
        className={classNames(styles.link, {[styles.link.wideView]: isOpenSideNav, [styles.activePath]: activePath}, className)}
        to={currentPathLink}
        onClick={() => analyticsService.event(analytics)}
      >
        <Hint offset={Hint.offsets.SM} side={Hint.sides.RIGHT} show={!isOpenSideNav} content={translate(name)}>
          <div className={classNames(styles.iconContainer)}>
            <Icon icon={iconName} color={color} hoverColor={hoverColor || Icon.colors.PRIMARY_BRAND_REGULAR}/>
          </div>
        </Hint>
        <div
          className={classNames(className, styles.textContent, {
            [styles.wideView]: isOpenSideNav,
          })}
        >
          {translate(name)}
        </div>
      </Link>
    </li>
  );
};
```

Any help will be welcomed.
Thanks.

I have tried inspecting the prop drilling.
NavigationLInksView gets the right prop value every time it changes.
When drilling to a child, the Childs get it duplicated as shown in the screenshot.
The direct Childs sideBarButton and SideBarButtonWithSideMenu for some reason get it twice.
The value that they always take from the duplicated prop is "false", regardless of some scenarios being true.

[image: Parent]
[image: Child]

Comment: Can you make a running example here? https://codesandbox.io/s/new